# Extract files from packet payload

Tags: c, libpcap

Libpcap helps to capture network packets and save them in '.pcap' files. I know how to do this but how to extract files from the payload? I want to analyze pcap file, extract files (maybe using 'magic numbers' ?), guess their extension and *save these files so I can view them*. If someone downloaded a PNG image I want to get image.png on my computer. I know I can use Wireshark or any other sniffer but my aim is to *write my own one*.
**The question is: how do I extract files from pcap capture file?**

C code will be much appreciated.

**Notice:** WinPcap is OK, but it would be better if the code was multiplatform.

Comment: You can view the packet in wireshark

Comment: @Khan, I know, but I want to write my own lightweight packet sniffer. Wireshark works with lots of problems and slowdowns on Mac, so I wanna get a sniffer that works on every platform. Even on jailbroken iPhone.

Comment: Doesn't the pcap website/documentation tell you how to do that?

Comment: @o_weisman it's just about packet capturing but nothing else

Comment: http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcap__tut7.html ?

Answer (score 2):

Well you can use wireshark to view the packet. 
The link below shows you how to make your own packet sniffer in C

http://www.binarytides.com/packet-sniffer-code-c-linux/

Comment: I know perfectly well _how to capture packets_, but it would be once to have more info about payload processing.

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark is able to do that.

See: http://www.behindthefirewalls.com/2014/01/extracting-files-from-network-traffic-pcap.html